# Swift didTap Event is not call when i tap on Marker

Tags: swift, google-maps

didTap event is not call in my project

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapViewSecond: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    var zoomLevel: Float = 10.0
    var mapViewV: GMSMapView!
     var marker = GMSMarker()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 21.512740, longitude: 70.572224, zoom: 15.0)
        mapView.mapType = GMSMapViewType.hybrid
        mapView.camera = camera
        mapView.delegate = self
        showMarker(position: camera.target)
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }

    func showMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D){

        marker.position = position
        marker.title = "Palo Alto"
        marker.snippet = "San Francisco"
        marker.map = mapView
    }
}

extension ViewController : GMSMapViewDelegate{

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("didTapInfoWindowOf")
    }

    /* handles Info Window long press */
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("didLongPressInfoWindowOf")
    }

    /* set a custom Info Window */
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 70))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        let lbl1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 8, y: 8, width: view.frame.size.width - 16, height: 15))
        lbl1.text = "Hi there!"
        view.addSubview(lbl1)

        let lbl2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: lbl1.frame.origin.x, y: lbl1.frame.origin.y + lbl1.frame.size.height + 3, width: view.frame.size.width - 16, height: 15))
        lbl2.text = "I am a custom info window."
        lbl2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .light)
        view.addSubview(lbl2)

        return view
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        marker.position = coordinate
    }
}
```

Comment: [didTapMarker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#ae291e1bff99f9d06428ced09daf5802d) method is called when you tap on marker

Answer (score 0):

You did not implement didTapMarker.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
     print("Marker tapped")
     return true
}
```

Comment: but how can I identify which marker is tapped?